# Find a GPU with enough memory

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I want to programmatically find out the available GPUs and their current memory usage and use one of the GPUs based on their memory availability. I want to do this in PyTorch.

I have seen the following solution in this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/access-gpu-memory-usage-in-pytorch):

```python
import torch.cuda as cutorch

for i in range(cutorch.device_count()):
    if cutorch.getMemoryUsage(i) > MEM: 
        opts.gpuID = i
        break
```

but it is not working in PyTorch 0.3.1 (there is no function called, `getMemoryUsage`). I am interested in a PyTorch based (using the library functions) solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Improve the code to show result of `cutorch.getMemoryUsage(i)` and put also that result in your question.

Comment: In other words, **edit your question** to explain *exactly* what "it is not working" means

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the webpage you give, there exist an answer:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import subprocess

def get_gpu_memory_map():
    """Get the current gpu usage.

    Returns
    -------
    usage: dict
        Keys are device ids as integers.
        Values are memory usage as integers in MB.
    """
    result = subprocess.check_output(
        [
            'nvidia-smi', '--query-gpu=memory.used',
            '--format=csv,nounits,noheader'
        ])
    # Convert lines into a dictionary
    gpu_memory = [int(x) for x in result.strip().split('\n')]
    gpu_memory_map = dict(zip(range(len(gpu_memory)), gpu_memory))
    return gpu_memory_map

print get_gpu_memory_map()
```

Comment: thanks! I have seen that solution but I am looking for a solution without running `nvidia-smi` command. More interested to know if there is any PyTorch based solution.

Comment: You will need to add `result = result.decode('utf-8')` after `nvidia-smi`query for this to work under python3.